# PHP Loop Based on ID

Tags: php

I am currently working on articles/blog posts with PHP.

I want it to loop based on the article_id, with the highest value first.

My code

```
<?php
include_once('includes/connection.php');
include_once('includes/article.php');

$article = new Article;
$articles = $article->fetch_all();

<?php foreach ($articles as $article) { 

.........

}

?>
```

and my article.php

```
<?php

class Article {
    public function fetch_all() {
        global $pdo;

        $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM articles");
        $query->execute();

        return $query->fetchAll();
    }

    public function fetch_data($article_id) {
        global $pdo;

        $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE article_id = ?");
        $query->bindValue(1, $article_id);
        $query->execute();

        return $query->fetch();
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: And what is the question? "Please develop the solution?" is not what we do here.

Comment: What you mean by highest value.. order by article id?

Comment: Just add `Order By article_id DESC` in your SQL query. I think, It is what you want.

Comment: @Stefan Neubert I asked for which technique to use since I'm new. But thank you for being so nice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

> ORDER BY article_id DESC

in your query,

Answer (score 0):

To loop over a data set from a SQL database, you could just make the query sorted.

```
$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY article_id DESC");
```